# From a systemic functional approach, what would a transitivity analysis of 'be that as it may' show?

Tags: grammar

I found this beautifully organized [text](https://www.britannica.com/story/what-is-the-difference-between-daoism-and-confucianism) for my students to analyze in terms of thematic progression. I'll also ask them to provide a transitivity analysis of some of its clauses, but there's that expression that caught me off guard.

I suppose it's a relational process 'be' followed by the carrier 'that' (which is already odd).

Then we get to 'as it may'. Would you say it's a conjunctive adjunct followed by a carrier and an elliptical attributive process (may be)?

Is there any other way to interpret it?

Comment: You really should ask this question on the linguistics site: [link](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions)

Comment: What, please, is a transitivity analysis?

In any case, how is "be that as it may" problematic?